# Excel to Word: User-defined type not defined, missing Word library in reference

Tags: excel, ms-word, export, vba

I want to export some cells content in Excel to Word, I want to do like this

```
Sub CreateNewWordDoc()
     ' to test this code, paste it into an Excel module
     ' add a reference to the Word-library
     ' create a new folder named C:\Foldername or edit the filnames in the code
    Dim wrdApp As Word.Application
    Dim wrdDoc As Word.Document
    Dim i As Integer
    Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    wrdApp.Visible = True
    Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Add
     ' or
     'Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Open("C:\Foldername\Filename.doc")
     ' sample word operations
    With wrdDoc
        For i = 1 To 100
            .Content.InsertAfter "Here is a sample test line #" & i
            .Content.InsertParagraphAfter
        Next i
        If Dir("C:\Foldername\MyNewWordDoc.doc") <> "" Then
            Kill "C:\Foldername\MyNewWordDoc.doc"
        End If
        .SaveAs ("C:\Foldername\MyNewWordDoc.doc")
        .Close ' close the document
    End With
    wrdApp.Quit ' close the Word application
    Set wrdDoc = Nothing
    Set wrdApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

But when test the function Excel say "Compile error: User-defined type not defined"
I guess this i a libray missing, but I can't found any suitable in Tools->Reference (VBA),
like Microsoft Office World or Microsft Word... Where can I find them?

Answer (score 0):

The refence depends wich version of MSOffice you are using.
For me it's "Microsoft Word 12.0 Object Library"

Hope that helps.